# Getting method return value from many to many in grails

Tags: html, grails, groovy

I have a problem with getting one of the object via grails here is my code:

Grails domain:

```
class Circle
{
    String description
    int howMany
    static hasMany [rects: Rectangle]
    constraints = 
    {
        answer: blank false, nullable: false
    }
    Rectangle getRect(int x, int y)
    {
        Rectangle rect = Rectangle.findWhere(x: x, y: y);
        rect
    }

}

class Rectangle
{
    int x
    int y
    String description
    Circle circle
    constraints =
    {
        circle blank: false, nullable: false
        description blank: false, nullable: false
    }
}
```

I pass my circle object via controller to the view, of course object isn't null and have correct values.

grails controller:

```
...
return [figure: circle, howManyX: xCount, howManyY: yCount]
...
```

xCount and yCount tells me how many times I have to render my template in the view:

view:

```
...
<g:render template="figureTemplate" model="[bean: figure, posX: x, posY: y]"/> // x and y are a variables in grails foreach loop
...
```

and my template:

```
<input type="text" name="text_${poY}_${posX}" text="${fieldValue(bean: bean, field:     getRect(posX, posY).name)}
```

I know my code isn't correct because fieldValue is not a method to get a value from object method, but from object variable. So it's possible to get somehow value returning via method? Or I should use something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add two dimensional array which contains Rectangles on specific indexes, and return it from controller to view, and in the view I get values from this array and this works perfectly for me:

controller:

```
...
return [figure: circle, howManyX: xCount, howManyY: yCount, arr: doubleArray]
...
```

view:

```
<g:render template="figureTemplate" model="[bean: figure, posX: x, posY: y, rect: arr[x][y]"/>
```

template:

```
<input type="text" name="text_${poY}_${posX}" text="${rect.description}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are not referencing the objects by the name assigned in the controller.

If you return the following map in your controller:

**return [figure: circle, howManyX: xCount, howManyY: yCount]**

then you must reference the objects by the map KEY.

So if you want to reference the **"circle"** object, you need to use **${figure}**

in your view code and to references **"xCount"** , **${howManyX}**, and so forth.

Comment: Not related to your question, but more of a question/assumption about what you are trying to do. If you are attempting to reference the "rectangles" in your Circle object, Rectangle.findWhere may not always give you the correct result, since it look over ALL rectangle objects. You may want to use something like Rectangle.executeQuery and filter on the circle id.

Comment: I think it should be a comment instead of a answer, because it's not referencing my problem.. and it's only a "czech" mistake in code.

Comment: I was not allowed to comment b/c I just recently signed up and didn't have enough rep points; I guess I misunderstood your problem, I thought you could not reference the objects in controller from your view. Based on the code provided it looked as if you were accessing the wrong variable. Next time, I will ask for clarification. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: I didn't know that You are not allow to comment, but thanks for help ;)